# Lagged variables for Correlation analysis - fill or trim?

Tags: correlation, lags

I'm attempting to find out if there's any correlation between a dependent variable and lagged independent variables. Simple question yet I can't find any answers to this - should the dataset be trimmed by the longest lag or filled with 0? What would be the rationale behind it? Thanks.

Comment: Filling with 0 is arbitrary, trimming makes more sense (assuming the lag is not too big).